# System of PDE's with unknown functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

So by messing around with some stuff in my own research I came across this problem and I have no idea how to proceed. I suspect it may have something to do with solving systems of PDE's but I could be wrong. For all I know, there may be no analytic way to solve it.

Given a set of functions $ \left\{ f_i(x_1,...,x_n) \right\} $ $i=1,...,n$

Find a set of g's $ \left\{ g_j(x_1,...,x_n) \right\} $ $j=1,...,m$ that satisfy:

$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial_{g_1}}{\partial_{x_1}}f_1 + & \cdots & +  \frac{\partial_{g_1}}{\partial_{x_n}}f_n\\
    \frac{\partial_{g_2}}{\partial_{x_1}}f_1 + & \cdots & +  \frac{\partial_{g_2}}{\partial_{x_n}}f_n\\
  \vdots  &  & \vdots  \\
    \frac{\partial_{g_m}}{\partial_{x_1}}f_1 + & \cdots & +  \frac{\partial_{g_m}}{\partial_{x_n}}f_n\\
 \end{pmatrix}
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  G_1(g_1,...,g_m) \\
  G_2(g_1,...,g_m)  \\
  \vdots   \\
  G_m(g_1,...,g_m)
 \end{pmatrix}
 $

Where $ \left\{ G_j \right\} $ are some arbitrary functions expressed in terms of the little g's

Comment: The generic form of this system, even with $m=1,n=2$, is not solvable analytically. You must know something about $f$.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! I do know the form of $f$, that is given, it's the $g$ and $G$ I don't know.

Comment: That is, I'm trying to find some $g$ so that the right hand side can be expressed in terms of $g$.